# Scraping multiple select options using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am required to scrape PDF's from the website `https://secc.gov.in/lgdStateList`. There are 3 drop-down menus for a state, a district and a block.
There are several states, under each state we have districts and under each district there are blocks.

I tried to implement the following code. I was able to select the state, but there seems to be some error when I select the district.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = ("https://secc.gov.in/lgdStateList")
browser.get(url)
html_source = browser.page_source
browser.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
for name_list in soup.find_all(class_ ='dropdown-row'):
    print(name_list.text)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://secc.gov.in/lgdStateList')

selectState = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("lgdState"))
for state in selectState.options:
    state.click()
    selectDistrict = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("lgdDistrict"))
    for district in selectDistrict.options:
        district.click()
        selectBlock = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("lgdBlock"))
        for block in selectBlock.options():
            block.click()
```

The error I ran into is :

```py
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="lgdDistrict"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.106)
```

I need help crawling through the 3 menus.

Any help/suggestions would be really appreciated. Let me know of any clarifications in the comments.

Comment: How about doing the same using requests? All you need to know is the value of state, district and block in order to use them in payload to be sent with post http requests.

Comment: I am not that comfortable with requests, any resource/code shared could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you can find [the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cFdF.jpg) of different states. You can find the same from district and block dropdowns.

You should now use those values within payload to get the table you would like to grab data from:

```
import urllib3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

link = "https://secc.gov.in/lgdGpList"

payload = {
    'stateCode': '10',
    'districtCode': '188',
    'blockCode': '1624'
}

r = requests.post(link,data=payload,verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
for items in soup.select("table#example tr"):
    data = [' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.select("th,td")]
    print(data)
```

Output the script produces:

```
['Select State', 'Select District', 'Select Block']
['', 'Select District', 'Select Block']
['ARARIA BASTI (93638)', 'BANGAMA (93639)', 'BANSBARI (93640)']
['BASANTPUR (93641)', 'BATURBARI (93642)', 'BELWA (93643)']
['BOCHI (93644)', 'CHANDRADEI (93645)', 'CHATAR (93646)']
['CHIKANI (93647)', 'DIYARI (93648)', 'GAINRHA (93649)']
['GAIYARI (93650)', 'HARIA (93651)', 'HAYATPUR (93652)']
['JAMUA (93653)', 'JHAMTA (93654)', 'KAMALDAHA (93655)']
['KISMAT KHAWASPUR (93656)', 'KUSIYAR GAWON (93657)', 'MADANPUR EAST (93658)']
['MADANPUR WEST (93659)', 'PAIKTOLA (93660)', 'POKHARIA (93661)']
['RAMPUR KODARKATTI (93662)', 'RAMPUR MOHANPUR EAST (93663)', 'RAMPUR MOHANPUR WEST (93664)']
['SAHASMAL (93665)', 'SHARANPUR (93666)', 'TARAUNA BHOJPUR (93667)']
```

You need to scrape the numbers available in brackets adjacent to each results above and then use them in `payload` and send another post requests to download the pdf files. Make sure to put the script in a folder before execution so that you can get all the files within.

```
import urllib3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

link = "https://secc.gov.in/lgdGpList"
download_link = "https://secc.gov.in/downloadLgdwisePdfFile"

payload = {
    'stateCode': '10',
    'districtCode': '188',
    'blockCode': '1624'
}
r = requests.post(link,data=payload,verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select("table#example td > a[onclick^='downloadLgdFile']"):
    gp_code = item.text.strip().split("(")[1].split(")")[0]
    payload['gpCode'] = gp_code
    with open(f'{gp_code}.pdf','wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.post(download_link,data=payload,verify=False).content)
```