# Click an element to dynamically change content with python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm scraping all the data off my works website to get all my shifts and data about those shifts with python and beautiful soup. Scraping the shifts is fine since they are just elements. But to get info like who is working on a shift you have to click an element which displays a hidden element but also changes the info depending on which day you have clicked on. This is changed with a javascript function `showFloorPlan('N','N','N','20200624')`

I need to be able to scrape the data from a weeks worth of shifts showing who is working on which shift. I've tried added `javascript:showFloorPlan('N','N','N','20200624')` to the URL I am scraping from but with no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You could try using payloads. Try referring this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62500126/scrapping-multiple-select-options-using-selenium/62500586?noredirect=1#comment110532491_62500586 if you want to scrap data based on multiple options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try selenium library for browser-like actions like clicking, scrolling, navigating, and much more. Functionalities of BeautifulSoup are limited when it comes to dynamic scraping.

[Selenium Offical Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html)

[Selenium for python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

If you want to scrape without opening browser, you should also look for

[Headless Browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser)

Comment: Yeah I had a look at selenium, wasn't quite sure if it was going to do what I need tho from what I could see. Ideally need to just trigger that javascript function ```showFloorPlan()``` to then be able to scrape the data

Comment: selenium has ```execute_script()``` for that.